# Jetbrains Pycharm says pyramid and sqlalchemy libraries are undeclared

Tags: sqlalchemy, pyramid, pycharm

I have configured pycharm 2 to work with my pyramid project.

It says it can not find sqlalchemy and pyramid libraries and puts a red line under them. This is really annoying because I do not have autocomplete for these libraries.

But all my other libraries int virtual environment are being recognized in the project. I have double checked and the libraries are there in the virtualenv.

I have just moved from PyDev where it was working really fine. Any ideas on what I might have missed out?[image]

Comment: you've confirmed that pycharm is configured to look in your virtualenv?

Comment: Yeah. The cryptacular library above is only found in my virtualenv. Its not there in my system libs

Answer (score 0):

Please ensure that you have followed this guide, [Using PyCharm with Pyramid](http://docs.pylonsproject.org/projects/pyramid_tutorials/en/latest/pycharm/index.html).

If you still have issues, please follow up.

Also note that JetBrains has released [PyCharm 3 with two versions](http://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/), a free Community Edition and a Professional Edition.

Answer (score 0):

Under Preferences -> Project Interpter -> Python Interpreters

Make sure the pycharm library is on the path.  PyCharm is usually good at recognizing new modules, but you can manually tweak them here.  You might be able to install SQLAlchemy and Pyramid directly from PyCharm now, as they've added additional support for them in the new v3 of the IDE.

Answer (score 0):

Try [PyCharm 3](http://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/whatsnew/index.html) , it has support for `Pyramid Framework`.